# Hide canceled meeting invites on outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

When I try to hide cancelled meeting invites using the method recommended [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-to-hide-cancelled-events-from-calendar-in-the/17d4d7b9-5e07-4672-b388-d5cc80e5a0f9) I'm still facing one issue.

If someone sends a recurring invite and then cancels only one of those invites this method doesn't work. It only works when an individual meeting (not a part of a series) or the entire series is canceled. Does anybody know a workaround to this? Maybe a VBA code worst case.

PS: I'm using O365, but I'm sure this issue is there in all versions of outlook.